# Split column name and convert data from wide to long format in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a large dataset that I need to convert to long format from wide format.  That should be simple enough and there are lots of examples of how to do that on this forum.  However, in this case, I also need to split the column headers used in the wide format and create a column for each of them in the long format.

Example dataset

```
 data <- data.frame("East2010"=1:3, "West2010"=4:6, "East2011"=7:9, "West2011"=5:7)
 data
 East.2010 West.2010 East.2011 West.2011
 1         1         4         7         5
 2         2         5         8         6
 3         3         6         9         7
```

What I want is something like this

```
 Site   Year   Response
 East   2010   1
 East   2010   2
 East   2010   3
 West   2010   4
 West   2010   5
 West   2010   6
 East   2011   7
 East   2011   8
 East   2011   9
 West   2011   5
 West   2011   6
 West   2011   7
```

I have looked a lot of examples on this forum that will melt data to convert to long format and others that do a column split at a delimiter, but I have not been able to make the two work together.

Comment: +1 for the reproducible example of your input and clearly showing your expected output. Do also consider showing what you've tried for future questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the "modern day" :-) approach for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  gather(var, Response, East2010:West2011) %>%  ## Makes wide data long
  separate(var, c("Site", "Year"), sep = -5)    ## Splits up a column
#    Site Year Response
# 1  East 2010        1
# 2  East 2010        2
# 3  East 2010        3
# 4  West 2010        4
# 5  West 2010        5
# 6  West 2010        6
# 7  East 2011        7
# 8  East 2011        8
# 9  East 2011        9
# 10 West 2011        5
# 11 West 2011        6
# 12 West 2011        7
```

The `sep = -5` from above says to go from the end of the string backwards five characters and split there. Thus, if you had "North2010" as a possible name, this would still work.

That said, it is more reliable to use a regular expression like @David's, which is also possible within `separate`:

```
data %>%
  gather(var, Response, East2010:West2011) %>%
  separate(var, c("Site", "Year"), 
           sep = "(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[[:digit:]])", 
           perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or (in case the column width is not always constant).
Here I use a "lookahead" and "lookbehind" in order to separate characters from digits.

```
library(reshape2)
data <- melt(data)
temp <- strsplit(as.character(data$variable), "(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[[:digit:]])", perl = TRUE)
transform(data, Site = sapply(temp, "[", 1), Year = sapply(temp, "[", 2))

#   variable value Site Year
#1  East2010     1 East 2010
#2  East2010     2 East 2010
#3  East2010     3 East 2010
#4  West2010     4 West 2010
#5  West2010     5 West 2010
#6  West2010     6 West 2010
#7  East2011     7 East 2011
#8  East2011     8 East 2011
#9  East2011     9 East 2011
#10 West2011     5 West 2011
#11 West2011     6 West 2011
#12 West2011     7 West 2011
```

Comment: +1. What about `within(data, { temp <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(variable), "(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[[:digit:]])", perl = TRUE)); rm(variable) })`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto, nice one

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines would work:

```
library("plyr")
library("reshape2")
m.data <- melt(data)
m.data <- mutate(m.data, Site=substr(variable, 1,4), 
    Year=substr(variable, 5,8))
```

Which would result in:

```
> m.data
   variable value Site Year
1  East2010     1 East 2010
2  East2010     2 East 2010
3  East2010     3 East 2010
4  West2010     4 West 2010
5  West2010     5 West 2010
6  West2010     6 West 2010
7  East2011     7 East 2011
8  East2011     8 East 2011
9  East2011     9 East 2011
10 West2011     5 West 2011
11 West2011     6 West 2011
12 West2011     7 West 2011
```

Comment: Thanks Landroni!  This example works well for the example data that I provided.  What if the variable names could be variable in length (not always 4 letters like "East" and "West")?